# Resizing window function doesn't work when I use JavaScript to click a Bootstrap tab link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's a birds eye view of what I'm trying to accomplish, and for the most part it works. I'm trying to make my table behave like an Excel sheet where the headers stay in place as you scroll.

So I created a table with just headers and then each tab has tables in them. When the page first loads, it will grab the size of each column and make my headers tables (hTable) columns match the widths. When the browser is resized it fires of that function so everything matches. Everything is working perfectly like I need it to.

The problem now comes when I try to click on a tab using jQuery. For some reason, that line breaks the resizing code. I've placed the click function at the bottom of the page, at the top, in the $(function), outside of the function. That 1 single line of code breaks my resizing function and I can't figure out why.

Below you will find my code and the structure of my code. I've removed the content of the tables but the structure is still the same.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var curTab = 'E';

$(function(){

    hTableResize();
    $(window).resize(hTableResize);
    $('#tab-'+curTab).click(); // *** THIS BREAKS THE FUNCTIONALITY ***

}); //$(function){}

function hTableResize(){

    $('.cTable thead').hide();

    var col1 = $('.cTable td:eq(0)').width();
    var col2 = ($('.cTable td:eq(1)').width());
    var col3 = ($('.cTable td:eq(2)').width());
    var col4 = $('.cTable td:eq(3)').width();

    $('.hTable').css('width',col1+col2+col3+col4+'px !important');

    $('.hTable th:eq(0)').width(col1);
    $('.hTable th:eq(1)').width(col2);
    $('.hTable th:eq(2)').width(col3);
    $('.hTable th:eq(3)').width(col4);

}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenContainer">

  <p><span style="font-size:larger;"><b>Clients</b></span><br>
  <a href="#" class="but-editClientModal" data-clientid="0">+ Add Client</a></p>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="margin-top:7px; background-color:#ffffff; width: 100%;">
    <li role="presentation" class="" id="tA"><a href="#secA" aria-controls="secA" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-A" onclick="tab='A';" aria-expanded="false">A</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" id="tB"><a href="#secB" aria-controls="secB" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-B" onclick="tab='B';">B</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" id="tC"><a href="#secC" aria-controls="secC" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-C" onclick="tab='C';">C</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" id="tD"><a href="#secD" aria-controls="secD" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-D" onclick="tab='D';">D</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" id="tE"><a href="#secE" aria-controls="secE" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-E" onclick="tab='E';">E</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" id="tF"><a href="#secF" aria-controls="secF" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-F" onclick="tab='F';">F</a></li>

  </ul>

<table class="table-bordered table-hover table-striped hTable">
    <tbody><tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
        <th nowrap="" style="text-align: center; width: 82px;">Code</th>
        <th nowrap="" style="width: 0px;">Client Name</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 184px;">Sub</th>
        <th nowrap="" style="text-align: center; width: 149px;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
            Required</th>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:100%;">

<div class="tab-content">


    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secA">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped cTable" style="margin-bottom:250px;">
        <thead style="display: none;">
          <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <!-- <th nowrap align="center">ID</th> -->
            <th nowrap="" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th nowrap="">Client Name</th>
            <th align="center">Sub</th>
            <th nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
              Required</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>



    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secB">



        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped cTable" style="margin-bottom:250px;">
        <thead style="display: none;">
          <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <!-- <th nowrap align="center">ID</th> -->
            <th nowrap="" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th nowrap="">Client Name</th>
            <th align="center">Sub</th>
            <th nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
              Required</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>



    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secC">



        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped cTable" style="margin-bottom:250px;">
        <thead style="display: none;">
          <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <!-- <th nowrap align="center">ID</th> -->
            <th nowrap="" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th nowrap="">Client Name</th>
            <th align="center">Sub</th>
            <th nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
              Required</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>



    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secD">



        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped cTable" style="margin-bottom:250px;">
        <thead style="display: none;">
          <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <!-- <th nowrap align="center">ID</th> -->
            <th nowrap="" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th nowrap="">Client Name</th>
            <th align="center">Sub</th>
            <th nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
              Required</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>



    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secE">



        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped cTable" style="margin-bottom:250px;">
        <thead style="display: none;">
          <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <!-- <th nowrap align="center">ID</th> -->
            <th nowrap="" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th nowrap="">Client Name</th>
            <th align="center">Sub</th>
            <th nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
              Required</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>



    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secF">



        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped cTable" style="margin-bottom:250px;">
        <thead style="display: none;">
          <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <!-- <th nowrap align="center">ID</th> -->
            <th nowrap="" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th nowrap="">Client Name</th>
            <th align="center">Sub</th>
            <th nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">Consignor/Consignee <br>
              Required</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>



    </div>

</div>

</div> <!-- <div style="overflow-y: scroll;"> -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you trying to make the button click on page load on its own? asking because saying `$('#tab_curTab).click()` I believe is just triggering a click since you're not giving it a callback

Comment: You are correct... that's exactly what i'm trying to do... when the page loads, click on the tab. That breaks my code for some reason :\

Comment: try pulling your `$(window).resize()` out of the IIFE and then inside where you call `click()` try `$('#tab-'+curTab).trigger('click');`. also because you're using jquery you should be able to use `$(document).ready(function() {})` if you want instead of an IIFE 

`$(document).ready(function() {
    hTableResize();
    $('#tab-'+curTab).click();

    $(window).resize(hTableResize);
});`

try this at the end and also try pulling the resize out of the ready event

Comment: not sure what you mean by IIFE. Also, isn't $(function(){}) the same as $(document)...? I'll copy & paste that last bit of code you put up. and then i'll take the resize out... hopefully that does it. brb

Comment: So I tried exactly what you posted and nothing.. .same exact problem. Then i moved $(window).resize out of the ready function and it's still a no go :\. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hi Damien. I wonder if I might ask you to take a moment, before you post a question, to check spelling, case, etc? Stack Overflow is intended to be a long-term resource of useful questions, and thus spelling and readability matters to the community. Although we have volunteers editors (such as myself) who are willing to help curate and improve the excellent free resource we have, we do not have enough volunteer power to do all the edits we need, and especially if authors keep making the same errors.

Comment: In particular, the personal pronoun "I" is upper-case, with no exceptions. Product names are usually one initial cap, but there are exceptions: JavaScript, Bootstrap, jQuery. Paragraphs are also essential for readability - please don't add a wall of text! A para break can be inserted using double-Enter.